# Does this metric have an official name? Lévy metric? Ky Fan metric?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables taking values in a separable metric space $(S,d)$.  The metric I have in mind is
$$\rho(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[\min\{d(X,Y),1\}]$$
if $X$ and $Y$ take values in the a metric space $(S,d)$.

**Question: Does this metric have an official name?**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#L0.2C_the_space_of_measurable_functions) calls it the "Lévy metric for $L^0$".  Also, someone once told me they thought it was called the Lévy metric.  I can't find it anywhere else.  (If you Google™ it, don't use anything written by me as evidence that it is called the Lévy metric!)   Moveover, Lévy metric is the name for [another metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_metric).

I also know this metric metricizes convergence in probability (measure), and is equivalent to the Ky Fan metric (which I have also seen called the probability distance):
$$K(X,Y) = \inf\{\varepsilon \geq 0: P(d(X,Y) > \varepsilon) \leq \varepsilon\}.$$

I have also seen this very similar metric to mine
$$K^*(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d(X,Y)}{1 + d(X,Y)} \right]$$ called one of the "Ky Fan metrics".

I know I could just switch to the Ky Fan metric, but I wrote a long paper using this metric $\rho$ (calling it the Lévy metric), and I don't want to have to go through the whole thing and switch to the Ky Fan metric (and change my calculations) just because I know don't know what to properly call it.  (Also, I like this metric since it is reminiscent of the $L^1$-norm.)

Comment: I was wondering: the random variable $(X,Y)$ is measurable with respect to the product of the Borel $\sigma$-algebras ${\cal B}(S)\otimes{\cal B}(S)$. The map $d:S\times S\to\mathtt{R}^{+}$ being continuous is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}(S\times S)$. Don't you need to assume something like $S$ is separable to ensure that ${\cal B}(S\times S)={\cal B}(S)\otimes{\cal B}(S)$ so that $d(X,Y)$ is a measurable map and your expectation is well-defined?

Comment: @NoelVaillant, yes indeed.  I always work with separable metric spaces, so I sometimes forget to mention that assumption.  I added it.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a [Lévy metric](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=L%C3%A9vy_metric), or more generally the Lévy-Prokhonov metric, which is defined on distribution functions rather than random variables. However, as the following article points out, they are highly related despite this fundamental difference [("The Metrics of Prokhorov and Ky Fan
for Assessing Uncertainty in Inverse
Problems")](http://austriaca.at/0xc1aa5576%200x00239061.pdf). I can't say that the name Lévy metric does not sometimes refer to your metric $\rho$, but given the equivalence of $\rho$ with $K$, it would seem less confusing to just refer to it as a Ky Fan metric.

Comment: I just noticed that the OP specifically mentioned the existence of another Levy metric, but I'm going to leave the answer anyway.